# How to disable a submit button if input fields are empty in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

[image: Picture]

If the above fields are empty, no data may be sent and a Notify() message must appear. If the data has been entered, you can continue with the rest of the function. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there..

It should be

```
   If(IsBlank(TextInput.RequestedPurcahseQuantity),
        Notify.. ,
        ForAll..
    )
```

The code you currently have on the **If(IsBlank** line is used to enable/disable a button.
Without seeing the rest of your code I cannot advise whether there is an error causing the parsing to fail (causing the red squigly line under your code).  I find it's easier to start the code off simple, ensure it parses, then enhance it bit by bit.